# Correct way to transitionToRoute

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm making a live search on ember.js. This is the code

```
App.Router.map ->
    @resource "index", {path : "/"}
    @resource "index", {path : "/:query"}

App.Torrents =
    findByQuery : (query) ->
        url = "/api/find/#{query}"
        $.getJSON(url)

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend

    model : (params) ->
        App.Torrents.findByQuery(params.query)

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

    onChangeQuery : _.debounce(->
        query = @get("query")
        @transitionToRoute("index", {query  : query})
    , 500).observes("query")
```

I have a query property binded to an input. When the input change I want to transition to the route passing the new query parameter, but the IndexRoute.model method is not being called.

Comment: Which version of emberjs are you using ???  There was an inconsistency in `transitions` in previous versions of ember. But hopely this has been resolved with the `router facelift`

Comment: I have two resources because I'm trying to make the query parameter optional

Comment: This is the fiddle http://jsbin.com/ekaGipO/2/edit?html,js,output  it's written in javascript instead of coffee, but it's the same code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Selvaganesh/xJZ6Y/3/ ... Does this helps you ???

Comment: Actually my problem is fetching the model again when the query change because when I call transitionToRoute the model method of the route is not called again. Should I call the findByQuery method in onChangeQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason `IndexRoute.model` method not being called. is

> A route with a dynamic segment will only have its model hook called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), then a model context is already provided and the hook is not executed. Routes without dynamic segments will always execute the model hook.

explained [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).

So as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2904), use the `setupController` hook, to fetch your model, in these cases.

Working [bin](http://jsbin.com/ekaGipO/8/edit) of your code, with `setupController`

Comment: Notice, that if you pass a string as the dynamic segment to `transitionTo/transitionToRoute`, then the model hook will be hit. Pass an object, and it will be skipped, but `beforeModel` and `afterModel` are still hit.

Comment: honestly, the quotation provided has always confused me. It always sounds like: "The model hook only get called once on dynamic routes, but the model hook gets called every time on dynamic routes" doesn't make sense... I understood the meaning by now, but it still reads really confusing.

Comment: Is there anywhere any discussion about reasons of designing such behaviour? I'd like to know why they decided to do this that way...

Comment: This is so anti-intuitive. Why would there be such exceptions?

Comment: But a dynamic segment usually wants a different model. so why would they design it to  not to call the model hook? what on earth?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm late and this might not be of any use for you. I just wanted to post it over here, if in case it might be of any use for others.

This link helped me, clear my problem.

**Approach 1:** We could supply a model for the route. The model will be serialized into the URL using the serialize hook of the route:

```
var model = self.store.find( 'campaign', { fb_id: fb_id } );
self.transitionToRoute( 'campaign', model);
```

This will work fine for routing, but the URL might be tampered. For this case, we need to add extra logic to serialize the object passed into the new route and to correct the URL.

**Approach 2:** If a literal is passed (such as a number or a string), it will be treated as an identifier instead. In this case, the model hook of the route will be triggered:

```
self.transitionToRoute( 'campaign', fb_id);
```

This would invoke the model() and would correctly display the required URL on routing. setupController() will be invoked immediately after the model().

2nd one worked fine for me fine. Hope it's useful and answered the above question.